# Enable WP-postratings

Tags: wordpress, rating-system

I've created my own wordpress theme and installed WP-Postratings plugin, but it doesn't work. I add only

`<?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?>`

It show rating image, but i can't rate anything.

Should I add something to the functions, maybe the reason is ajax, should I add some function?

Comment: Check your console to see if you have any javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same plugin on my theme

Rating Buttons

```
if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); }
```

Rating Avarage

```
 if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { echo ''.expand_ratings_template('<span class="rating-images">%RATINGS_IMAGES%</span>', get_the_ID()); }
```

If it doesnt work you may have any javascript conflict , try to disable all plugins and try it again.You must be sure that admin-ajax.php is not blocked by server or anything else.

Comment: Could somebody help me? This plugin doesn't work in my own theme, in every other themes it works fine.

Comment: If it doesnt work with the codes above you may have one of the problems that I have explained above.1-JS Conflict and 2-admin-ajax.php is blocked by server or any security script.

Answer (score 0):

You should add something to the functions. That code is enough.

It usually happened because the plugin is crashed with another plugin. Disable another plugins one by one until you can rate. Then change the plugin that make the issue with the similar one.